# Why jboss terminates abruptly?

Tags: java, jboss

I have a jboss server running continuously, but after a day or two, it stops saying "Press any key to continue" in the console. I have checked the log file as well but there is no exception. Though the question looks abstract but if any of you have come across this can share any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Windows. You could try setting the environment variable mentioned in this documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/CLI+Recipes#CLIRecipes-Windowsand%22Pressanykeytocontinue...%22issue

But i'm not sure it will help. It's not clear that there is a connection between the batch interpreter asking you to press a key to continue, and JBoss terminating.

The best solution would obviously be to work on Unix instead of Windows, but i imagine that is out of scope!